# How can I disable a Qt widget without changing its appearence

Tags: qt, qt4.7

I have a Qt widget which has a layout and there are more widgets inside it. When I disable the widget the whole widget becomes little faded and no modifications are possible anymore. I want the features that comes with disabling a widget but I do not want it's appearance to change. Please let me know how this can be done.

Few ideas that comes to my mind:

1. Rather disabling widget, capture all the events on the widget and do nothing
2. Update style sheet for disabled state (not sure if possible)

Comment: I know this doesn't completely answer your question, but you can set most input widgets to read only, and you can set any icons you have to have the same appearance whether it is enabled or not, all in the property editor

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Capture events

Use `QObject::installEventFilter()` and `QObject::eventfilter()`.
Keep in mind the way Qt dispatch GUI events, in particular children get events first. So you need to install the event filter recursively on all widgets and watch for `QEvent::ChildAdded`.

### 2. Using stylesheets

This is a not a good solution. Stylesheets tend to break `QStyle` mechanisms which may lead to side effects.

### 3. Use a `QPixmap`

Hide all the child widgets, render them to a `QPixmap` and draw the pixmap in the `paintEvent`.